# What's included with railcard or what's included in railcard

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, word-meaning

What's the difference between the below sentences when I use *with* or *in* behind the included?

> What's included **with** railcard?
>
> What's included **in** railcard?

Comment: If "railcard" is a proper noun, like a name, it should be capitalized, like *Railcard*.  If it's just a noun, it would be countable, so it should be "a railcard" or "the railcard".

Answer (score 3):

I would say that when you use *in,* it becomes an integral part of the product. You cannot *detach* it.

Say,

> What's included in the *package?* ~ Well, an air ticket, sightseeing, and a guide.

On the other hand, *with* can have extra things that are detachable or separate but come with it.

> A bluetooth device is free *with* this phone.

In your example, if you say 'with', I may understand that there is a nice packaging of the Railcard and *with* it, there is something extra, maybe, a freebie! Say, a cover to keep the card.

On the other hand, if you say that what is 'in,' I'd understand that the card has free rides or maybe some features.

In short, in this context, *in* may talk about the *features,* and *with* about something physical.

**Note** that you can have benefits by using *with.*

> With the railcard comes many benefits - you can have 3 rides free every month.